# Can a View or Partial View determine whether it is cached or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one action has these attributes:

```
  [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server, Duration = 300, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

and another with

```
  [OutputCache(Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

and they both use the same View.

In the View, or even in the Action Method, how to I determine what the caching is? i.e. is it a cached page or not? I've tried looking at Response.Headers (only has "Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0), & Response.CacheControl is "private" in both cases.

Comment: shouldn't a view be agnostic as to whether it is cached or not?

Comment: If this is something the View should be aware of, shouldn't it be included on your Model?

Comment: I would say my main use is actually in a Partial View, where it would show e.g. a Join Now link for non-members, and not for logged-in members. I'm using a VaryByCustom in the attribute. It's a little more complicated than that, but being able to determine in code what the cache attribute was would save me from adding to the model or duplicating the cache setting in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this in the application, but for the sake of seeing if it's possible, I've done this sample... using Reflection, and a base controller, and calling Initialize() from my action method, the following code gets the OutputCache attributes from the calling method. Then a View or Partial View can get the cache location from the ViewBag.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();

        if (stackTrace.FrameCount >= 1)
        {
            var methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

            var filters = (OutputCacheAttribute[])methodBase.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OutputCacheAttribute), false);

            if (filters.Length > 0)
            {
                ViewBag.CacheLocation = filters[0].Location;
            }
        }
    }
}
```